# Rails Tutorial - weird RSpec behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm currently in [section 10.3.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#sec%3acreating_microposts) of the Rails Tutorial (beta) and ran into some problems with RSpec.

`rspec spec/ runs` perfectly, however if I do `rspec spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb` as described in the tutorial I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Micropost pages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb__567210303736562711_70234980477780'
     # ./app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___61006871036382679_70234970424160'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Performing the test manually in the web browser seems to work perfectly as well.

Not sure if I did something wrong or if there's a "bug" in the tutorial. Can anyone give a hint?

---

**UPDATE 1:** Here's a link to the [whole project on GitHub](https://github.com/znq/sample_app/tree/396d503d52b437790859917ce710c1aa59d3a426).

---

**UPDATE 2:** I now found out that when I restart the `rails server` I get the error, too, when I hit the page the first time. But when I load the page a second time (reload) then it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please [gist](https://gist.github.com/) your spec_helper, affected spec, controller and view. Great would be to push your complete application on github ;)

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/znq/sample_app/tree/396d503d52b437790859917ce710c1aa59d3a426

Comment: Can you try changing `<%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>` in home.html.erb to `<%= render :partial => "shared/micropost_form", :locals => { :micropost => @micropost } %>` and then use `form_for(micropost)` in _micropost_form.html.erb ?

Comment: @DanS I changed it, but didn't help :-( I also added some more information. See UPDATE 2 in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Rather stupid mistake. In my `static_pages_controller.rb` I had

```
  def home
    def home
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
    end
  end
```

Thanks anyway for the tips.